# Rx transform Observable<List<T>> to Observable<T>

Tags: java, rx-java, observable

I have `Observable<List<T>>` observable that emits many `List<T>` instances.
I want to transform observable to return all T items in single list.

**The specific questions is:**

How to transform `Observable<List<T>>` to `Observable<T>` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
observable.flatMapIterable(collection -> collection)
```

Keep in mind that this too does not guarantee order.

Comment: This does guarantee an ordered expansion of the collection. It drains one collection and when switches to the next.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It seems that flat map operator is doing desired transformation:

```
 observable.flatMap((List<T> ts) -> Observable.from(ts)).toList();
```

Comment: The order will not necessarily be preserved. If you care about the order use `concatMap` instead of `flatMap`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is flatMap the iterable object:

```java
observable.flatMapIterable(Functions.identity()).toList();

// or

observable.flatMap(Observable::fromIterable).toList();
```